# What's the practical use of KeyedStream#max

Tags: apache-flink

I have a simple Flink application to illustrate the usage of `KeyedStream#max`

```
import com.huawei.flink.time.Box
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, _}

object KeyStreamMaxTest {

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
    env.setParallelism(1)
    env.setMaxParallelism(1)
    val ds = env.fromElements(("X,Red,10"), ("Y,Blue,10"), ("Z,Black, 22"), ("U,Green,22"), ("N,Blue,25"), ("M,Green,23"))
    val ds2 = ds.map { line =>
      val Array(name, color, size) = line.split(",")
      Box(name.trim, color.trim, size.trim.toInt)
    }.keyBy(_.color).max("size")

    ds2.print()

    env.execute()

  }

}
```

The output is:

```
Box(X,Red,10)
Box(Y,Blue,10)
Box(Z,Black,22)
Box(U,Green,22)
Box(Y,Blue,25)  -- I thought this should be ("N,Blue,25")
Box(U,Green,23)
```

Looks Flink only replaces the size， but keeps name and color unchanged,

I would ask what's the practical usage for this behavior?  I could only imagine that it is natural to get the whole record that has the max size.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all you need to know is the max value, for each key, of one field. I believe `max` is able to provide this information while doing less work than the more generally useful `maxBy`, which returns the whole record that has the max size.